# AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'read' when calling requests.post

Tags: python-3.x, rest, python-requests

I'm trying to post a request that with `curl` looks like this:

```
curl -X POST \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer 48378438…" \
    --header "X-Backtory-Storage-Id: 125653265" \
    --form fileItems[0].fileToUpload=@"/path/to/file1.txt"  \
    --form fileItems[0].path="/path1/path2/"    \
    --form fileItems[0].replacing=true  \
    http://storage.backtory.com/files
```

And my code is something like this:

```
upload_headers = {'Authorization':'Bearer' + ' ' + access_token, 'X-Backtory-Storage-Id':'48378438**********'}
upload_data = {'fileItems[0].fileToUpload': open('file.txt', 'rb'), 'fileItems[0].path': r'/path1/', 'fileItems[0].replacing': True}
upload_response = requests.post("http://storage.backtory.com/files", files=upload_data, headers=upload_headers)
print(upload_r)
```

But after running this code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "backtory-test.py", line 27, in <module>
    upload_r = requests.post("http://storage.backtory.com/files", files=upload_data, headers=upload_headers)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 112, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 494, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 437, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 308, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 496, in prepare_body
    (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 159, in _encode_files
    fdata = fp.read()
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Which section of my code is buggy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every value in the `files` dictionary must be a file-descriptor-like object (ie have a `read` method) or a tuple (see below).

`True` neither has such method (as the error says) nor is a tuple.

So

```
upload_data = {'fileItems[0].fileToUpload': open('file.txt', 'rb'), 
               'fileItems[0].path': r'/path1/',
               'fileItems[0].replacing': True}
```

should simply be

```
upload_data = {'filename': open('file.txt', 'rb')}
```

Another option is to provide a tuple as a value. This allows you to set some options. You can read more on [`requests` docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file).

`path` and `replacing` sound like variables that you should post as data and not as part of the `files` dictionary.